# How to find common numbers in a list of a list of numbers and assign it to a letter, then append to show a string of letters?

Tags: python, list

I have list of a list of 4 numbers which I need to convert to a list of letters and each set is independent of the previous set. I then want to append the letters string to a new list. For example: 
['001', '001', '001', '001'] into ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'] 
['014', '013', '013', '023'] into ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'] 
['001', '001', '001', '003'] into ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'] 
['001', '001', '001', '004'] into ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']

```
Polymer_data = Polymer_data.sort_values(['ID'])
for i in Polymer_data.ID:
    print(i.split('-'))

['001', '001', '001', '001']
['001', '001', '001', '002']
['001', '001', '001', '003']
['001', '001', '001', '004']
...
['025', '022', '024', '025']
['025', '023', '024', '025']
['025', '024', '024', '025']
['025', '025', '025', '025']
```

The expected results should be:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
...
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Edit: To clarify each list is independent of each other, so the 1st unique value in each list is assigned 'A', 2nd unique value is 'B', etc.

Also the range of values are from 001-025, the '...' represents all the values in between that I didn't write out (not sure how to format this). So in total there's a list of 195625 possible combinations from 001-025 arranged in a pattern of 4.

Comment: Why all `002`, `003` and `004` are mapped to `B`?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in each of the number lists, the first unique value gets assigned `A` and second one as `B` and so forth?

Comment: Is every chunk of data filled with four possible values (`001`-`004`, `022`-`025`) and every value should be mapped to `A`-`D`? Smallest to `A`, highest to `D`?

Comment: Yes, each list is independent from the other, so the first unique value is A, second unique value is B, 3rd unique is C and 4th is D.

Answer (score 1):

1. use `ord` to get code number from 'A'
2. clear item duplicated from original list
3. get and add an index to code from 'A'
4. use `chr` to convert it to a character

You can understand from this sample code as following:

```
lists = [['001', '001', '001', '002', '001', '003'],
         ['021', '022', '020', '021', '025', '022']]

result = []
for lista in lists:
    code = ord('A')
    listb = list(set(lista))
    listb.sort()
    result.append([chr(listb.index(x)+code) for x in lista])

print (result)
```

Result is

```
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']]
```

Comment: Using `ord()` and `chr()` is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be elegant at all. The only benefit is you can change the assigned value easily if you plan to use something other than `A, B, C, D`

```
input_lists = [
['001', '001', '001', '001'],
['001', '001', '001', '002'],
['001', '001', '001', '003'],
['001', '001', '001', '004'],
['025', '022', '024', '025'],
['025', '023', '024', '025'],
['025', '024', '024', '025'],
['025', '025', '025', '025']
]

assignment = { '0' : 'A', '1': 'B', '2': 'C', '3': 'D'}  # dictionary for value assignment

for i,input_list in enumerate(input_lists):
    list_set = set(input_list)  # create a set of unique values in each "sub" list
    unique_list = list(list_set)  # convert the set back to a list for indexing
    for j,val in enumerate(input_list):
        val_assign = assignment[str(unique_list.index(val))]
        input_lists[i][j] = val_assign  # write the assigned value directly back to the input lists

print(input_lists)
```